# Sharepoint task form and document approval

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

Hi
I am working on Sharepoint 2010. 
Here is the requirement

I have a List based on a document content type. When a document is uploaded to the list, it has to be approved by three people sequentially.
personA approves - personB - person C approves. 
when person C approves. the document is approved / published ot have a major version and is sent to a record center

I created a workflow. It just has one task CreateTaskwithContent  type..

**Why does the status say "Completed" when the task created?**

I have a custom task edit form. When the user clicks on the task , this form is opened. When person C approves, i want the workflow to be completed.
How do i do this? Do i create another field in the task list and use it as a reference? or ? 
Or do i have to use the extendedproperties in workflow? If that how do i use those in task edit forms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work flow says "Completed" when it is done going through its flow.

In your case, I would assume that the workflow does nothing after the task is created.  If you want it to continue after the task is created (wait for the task to be completed, for example) you'll need to edit your workflow and add additional steps.